# Is the difference of ideals an ideal?

Tags: ideals

I am studying ideals and noticed that $I+J$ is an ideal as noted [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-1.pdf). However the paper does not discuss $I-J$ so:

**Is the difference of ideals an ideal?**

Comment: $a\in J\iff -a\in J$ so that $-J=J$ and $I-J:=I+(-J)=I+J$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, because

$$I-J = \{i - j \mid i \in I, j \in J\} = \{i + (-j) \mid i \in I, j \in J\} = \{i + k \mid i \in I, -k \in J\} = \{i + k \mid i \in I, k \in -J\} = \{i + k \mid i \in I, k \in J\} = I + J$$

(because obviously $-J = J$).